Github Actions deployment of Azure Functions stopped working
Recently our deployment script that used to build and deploy Azure Functions on GitHub Actions stopped working. It still works out and deploys all green, yet no Function instances in the Azure Function show up.
Script is pretty straight forward:
job 1, build:
    dotnet publish
    actions/upload-artifact@v4

job 2, deploy:
    actions/download-artifact@v4
    azure/login@v2
    azure/functions-action@v1


Starting September 2, 2024 actions/upload-artifact@v3 and v4 exclude hidden files from artifacts by default.
Published Azure Function contains folder .azurefunctions which is considered hidden. Respectively, now they are not included into artifacts and published this way functions are not operational.
To revert to original behavior you need to add flag include-hidden-files: true to it.
So much of relying on the action version for reproducible builds.
